# Can't download python idle for Python 3.2.3 Windows 64 bit

Tags: installation, python-idle, python-3.2

I need a line by line debugger for Python.  I thought I should start with idle.  I went to python.org and downloaded Python 3.2.3 for 64 bit Windows.  Most Python documentation states that all installations automatically download IDLE.  I installed Python in c:\Python32.  I don't see idle.exe or any folder named idle in this folder or any of its subfolders.  I then searched Google and tried to see how I could download idle.  It seems that there is no separate download for idle--or not one that matches 64 bit.

Can you recommend quickest solution?

1. Install a different version for Windows 64 bit(will this ruin my 3.2.3 installation?)
2. Give up on IDLE install a different IDE (tried PyScripter and couldn't figure out how to do line by line debugging in one step.  PyScripter is far inferior to Visual Studio but it's free.)  Tried pythonfiddle and couldn't figure out how to set breakpoints.  Tried pythontutor and couldn't figure out how to set breakpoints.

ANSWER TO THIS QUESTION (I can't post this answer because of low reputation.)

Someone on www.udacity.com provided me with the answer!  The answer was that you launch idle by typing `pythonw c:\python32\lib\idlelib\idle.py`

I would never have thought of this in a million years!  I assumed that idle was an executable.  Instead, it is a python script.

Also I learned that other versions of python don't ruin your installation, they just end up in a different folder.

I learned about Aptana studio with Pydev and Visual Studio 10 with Python from stack overflow.  So I will try these idle applications if idle isn't working for me.

Comment: please move your answer into an answer - reputation is not a barrier. All users can answer questions - http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-posts

Comment: also, if what you are after is a debugger, try using the pdb package. It ships with Python and is nice and easy to use

Comment: The Idle code is in Lib/idlelib.  On Windows, Idle is usually started from the start menu or a pinned icon.  In the console, `python -m idlelib` works or with 3.3 or the py launcher installed,  `py -3 -m idlelib`.  Idle does have a debugger based on bdb (as is pdb), but I just fixed an obnoxious bug for 3.4.2 and 2.7.9 (not released yet).